# Extracting columns from table Excel and merging them into another table

Tags: excel, r, csv

I have many (hundreds) excel documents with around 10 columns and 10 rows each.

My objective is to create *separate* txt files containing the first column and the second column, then another file containing the first and the third and so on... and the same for the rest of excel files.

Is there any way of doing this in Excel? Rather, would it be possible to apply a batch command in R to get into the Excel files (previously exported to CSV or of the kind) to produce separate txt files containing the pairing of columns?

Comment: For getting all files to csv, you could use something like what is presented at [this location](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/script-convert-excel-ss-to-csv/16265.html). That should save you some work. You may need to adapt the VBScript code a little, but the idea is there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one possible way to do it in R. This is only for one csv file, but it can easily be adapted for many files.

```
##Simulate data
write.csv(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10),file="test.csv",row.names=FALSE)
data1<-read.csv("test.csv")

##Create the matrix containing the columns numbers for exporting. 
##Note the code is not nice. There is a function which gives this 
##matrix immediately, but I forgot it.
rr<-numeric()
for(i in 1:9) for(j in (i+1):10) rr<-rbind(rr,c(i,j))

##Write the columns in separate files
for(i in 1:nrow(rr)) write.csv(data1[,rr[i,]],file=paste("output1_",paste(rr[i,],collapse="_"),".csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE)
```

This code takes one file named `test.csv` and produces files of type `output1_coln1_coln2.csv` where `coln1` and `coln2` are the column numbers.

For many files wrap this into a function and loop over all csv files.

Answer (score 1):

And with the looping over files:

```
fnames<-list.files(pattern = "myFile*.csv")
fnums<-as.integer(sub(".csv", "", sub("myFile", "", fnames, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE))

for(i in seq_along(fnums))
{
    dta<-read.csv(fnames[i])
    #halfnumcols<-dim(dta) %/% 2
    #for(j in (seq(halfnumcols)-1))
    #{
    #   write.csv(dta[,j*2+c(1,2)], paste("resultFile", i, ".", (j+1), ".csv", sep=""))
    #}
    #EDIT: instead of neighbor pairs, run over all pairs
    numcols<-dim(dta)[2]
    apply(combn(seq(numcols), 2), 2, function(curcomb){
        write.csv(dta[,curcomb)], paste("resultFile", i, ".", curcomb[1], ".", curcomb[2], ".csv"))
    })
}
```

Comment: @Nick, I also fixed small typo in the first for loop, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @mpiktas. No problem at all. Thanks for pointing it out. That'll teach me posting a "solution" without testing it (stackoverflow is not the best R editor around). Would have been hard without the files anyway...

Comment: @Nick, if I am not mistaken the first iteration of the second loop will select the zero column of data.frame `dta`, which is not good.

Comment: @Nick, you probably wanted `halfnumcols<-ncol(dta) %/% 2`, but still the code will not go through all the combinations the OP wanted, i.e. 1,1; 1,2; 1,3; ... 1,n; 2,3; 2,4; ... 2,n; ... etc.

Comment: @jarry - consider using XLConnect or another package that can directly read the xls files. Saving all of those files as a csv would be a pain :)

Comment: +1, `combn` this a function which I forgot, thanks. Final nitpick, using "." as a separator in file name might pose problems in Windows environment :)

Comment: @Chase, Excel is pain too. Dealing with a lot files is not a big deal if your filesystem is not FAT.